# STM32 + LwIP + DP83848 - No results when I ping

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, ethernet, microprocessor, network

I have made a PCB with an STM32F407 processor and I have been used DP83848 Ethernet PHY.
For STM32F407 processor. I have selected RMII settings.

[image]

[image]

The pinouts for the RMII settings.

[image]

Red rings got to the processor.
The blue ring shows RESET. It need to be logic 1 (HIGH) for the Ethernet PHY to start.
The green ring shows a LED lamp that flashes when something happen on the internet cable e.g I ping an IP-address.

[image]

The oscillator is at 50 Mhz and I don't know why it should go inside my processor.
This is from the datasheet DS8626 of the ST-microcontroller. https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/dm00037051.pdf

[image]

I think this is OK to just write 50 MHz for Ethernet PTP?

[image]

I have connected my RJ45 connector like this

[image]

[image]

Other tiny pins of the Ethernet PHY

[image]

Pins that are not used are:

[image]

Special pinns:

[image]

Some pins have Pull-up and pull-down. I have pull-downs on all input pins of the ethernet PHY.

[image]

Last picture is the LwIP configuration.
Were I select the IP address and the ram address at 0x20014000 with a size of 1600 bytes.
My RAM address goes from 0x2000000 to 0x20020000 e.g 128 kB.

[image]

[image]

```
/* USER CODE BEGIN 0 */

extern struct netif gnetif;

int main(){
/* USER CODE END 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN 1 */

  /* USER CODE END 1 */

  /* MCU Configuration--------------------------------------------------------*/

  /* Reset of all peripherals, Initializes the Flash interface and the Systick. */
  HAL_Init();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN Init */

  /* USER CODE END Init */

  /* Configure the system clock */
  SystemClock_Config();

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SysInit */

  /* USER CODE END SysInit */

  /* Initialize all configured peripherals */
  MX_GPIO_Init();
  MX_FSMC_Init();
  MX_DCMI_Init();
  MX_SPI2_Init();
  MX_TIM1_Init();
  MX_TIM3_Init();
  MX_ADC1_Init();
  MX_CAN1_Init();
  MX_RTC_Init();
  MX_TIM4_Init();
  MX_DMA_Init();
  MX_UART5_Init();
  MX_LWIP_Init();
  /* USER CODE BEGIN 2 */
  
  /* Activate DP83848 */
  HAL_GPIO_WritePin(ETH_RESET_GPIO_Port, ETH_RESET_Pin, GPIO_PIN_SET);

  while (1)
  {
    /* USER CODE END WHILE */

    /* USER CODE BEGIN 3 */

      ethernetif_input(&gnetif);

      sys_check_timeouts();
  }
```

**Result:**

Nothing happens when I ping

[image]

Only the LED D1 flashes when I ping. So that means the pin LED_ACT/COL at my Ethernet PHY goes from HIGH to LOW when something happening at the ethernet cable. Right?

[image]

[image]

**Question:**

What should I do in STM32CubeIDE to make my processor work with the Ethernet PHY? What have I missed?

I have follow this manual that shows how to connect a processor to the network using LwIP and an external Ethernet PHY.

https://controllerstech.com/stm32-ethernet-1-connection/

Comment: Not quite sure where to start here ... What part number is your RJ45 jack?

Comment: @TomL. 710-74990101212 Here: https://eu.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Wurth-Elektronik/74990101212?qs=h3%2Fj8evtlm23Z4vFTgXIOQ%3D%3D

Comment: Do you have a development board with Ethernet? If so, test your code on that 1st. Do you see the MAC address in Wireshark? Even without an IP stack, there should be some communication between your board and the switch/PC.

Comment: I think you are going to have to start with the basics and step through each issue. Triple validate against reference schematics, then validate phy to MCU, then phy to network, and so on. There is just simply too much here to process for drive by answers unfortunately. It's the type of problem best solved methodically and with colleagues if they are available. I don't know about lwip, but in freertos you can debug to view phy connectivity.

Comment: @LiorBilia I have a custom board.

Comment: @ErikFriesen I think I will start from the beginning. I have checked that I'm using the correct PHY address. That's 0x1 for the Ethernet PHY.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer now. Here is the solution:

https://community.st.com/s/question/0D73W000001oJX8SAM/detail

Easy! Step by step.

Comment: euraad - Hi, This is a "link-only" answer and one reason those aren't allowed is because they become useless if the link dies. And the link to the solution you self-answered has now died :( I checked the Wayback Machine (Internet Archive) and it isn't there. Unfortunately, without having the title of the thread you originally linked, I can't help you by searching for that thread on the reorganised ST forum and fixing the link for you. Can you please try to (a) update the link in this answer to a working one, and (b) Include the essential parts of the linked solution into your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I will update the link...or give the answer if ST have fixed the issue. They told me that this year week 23, they are going to update the firmware of ST for just LwiP

Comment: (For those readers who find this topic and see the link in the question is broken, I *think* (not sure) that [this](https://community.st.com/t5/stm32-mcus-embedded-software/stm32f407-lwip-dp83848-cannot-ping-why/m-p/61477) is the equivalent new link on the reorganised ST forum - in case that helps someone.)

Answer (score 1):

you should check that you are following the IP schema for your router if you connected to it.

Comment: Could you [edit] and expand upon your answer?